# Issue with invoking Mock in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have taken up Python recently.
I'm trying to use `unittest.Mock()` for testing my code in PyCharm. But, PyCharm fails with the error:

```
requests = Mock()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

My program:

```
import requests
from unittest import Mock


requests = unittest.Mock()


def get_holidays():
    r = requests.get("http://localhost/holidays")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.json()
    return None
```

Can anyone please help to identify where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have imported `Mock` from the `unittest` module, but you're trying to use it as `unittest.Mock()` instead of just `Mock()`. Try this instead:

```
import requests
from unittest.mock import Mock

requests = Mock()

def get_holidays():
    r = requests.get("http://localhost/holidays")
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.json()
    return None
```